# Exporting Google cloud video intelligence model

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've trained a video classification model using Google's video intelligence platform, I want to now download the model to predict on-prem for security purpose but I don't see anyway of exporting the model. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inform you that indeed you are right. As of today the [AutoML Video Intelligence](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/automl/docs/) is on Beta and there is no way to export your model.

I would advise you to stay alert for the [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/automl/docs/release-notes) to check for updates on the product.